Reduced dynamics for the pure state of the system
First consider a closed system.
If it is known a priori that the initial state of the system is a pure state $| \phi \rangle$, then the von Neumann equation for the density matrix is
$$
\frac{d \rho}{dt} = -i [ H, \rho ]
$$
can be "simplified" to the Schrödinger equation
$$
\frac{d\phi (t) }{dt} = -i H \phi (t).
$$
Now consider a system interacting with a reservoir. The state of the reservoir is given by the $\omega$ functional. The evolution of the observable is given by the von Neumann equation
$$
\frac{dY}{dt} = i [ H, \rho ].
$$
For considering of a reduced dynamic, we introduce the mapping $\omega'$ given by the identity $\omega' (A \otimes B ) = A \cdot \omega ( B )$, where $A$ is the observable of the system and $B$ is the observable of the reservoir. Then the reduced dynamics is given as
$$
X(t) = \omega' ( e^{iH t} ( X \otimes I ) e^{-iH t}   ).
$$
My question is as follows. If the state of the system is known to be a pure $| \phi\rangle $ state, is it possible to simplify the von Neumann equations of reduced dynamics by analogy to the case of a closed system?

While the purity is preserved in closed systems, in the system-environment picture this does not hold anymore. Indeed, a Taylor expansion around $t=0$ yields
$$
X(t)=X+it[\omega'(H),X]+t^2L(X)+\mathcal O(t^3)
$$
with $L:=\omega'(H((\cdot)\otimes I)H)-\frac12\omega'(H^2)(\cdot)-\frac12(\cdot)\omega'(H^2)$ of Lindblad form. Thus only the first derivative preserves the purity, while the second derivative—and thus the entire evolution—will in general transform a pure state into a mixed state. In other words the $t^2$ contribution is the reason why the pure-state reduction in the closed-system case does not work anymore.
